# Import all objects from Oracle to Visual Studio Database Project

Tags: visual-studio-2010, import, oracle11g, database-project

I have a Oracle database to which I connect from Visual Studio 2010 (Oracle Developer Tools). I now have the database in the "Server Explorer" window and can see all Tables, Views, Functions, etc.

Now I want to have all those objects in my database project solution (I want to use the version control of TFS, that's the reason I want all objects in my solution). I can right click a **single** function and choose "Generate Create Script to Project", then it will do exactly what I want, it creates a new script in the "Functions" folder of the database project, with the same name as the function.

**Problem:**
If I select two or more functions and use the "Generate Create Script to Project" function, then I have to choose a name for the script and it will write all the functions in one script. But I want a single file per script.

**Question:**
Is it somehow possible to export all objects from the oracle database and import them as script in the Visual Studio database project?

If I use a different driver (devart), then I am able to do it, but we want to use the ODT and I couldn't find an easy way to complete that task there.
Edit: Just noticed, that the devart project is not compatible with source control, so we absolutely have to go with ODT.

Comment: stuck with the same problem. apparently oracle keep on delivering half baked projects

Comment: Yep. Been fighting with it for days. Crap!